# Twilio > Google Ads Conversion tracking

Tags: twilio

Anyone here have experience in setting up Google Ads Conversion Tracking with Twilio.

Our Google technical support rep advised that we need to first add Google Dynamic Number Insertion on our landing pages and have that forward to our dedicated Twilio #.

I am just not sure if that would even work because Google Conversion tracking works off of the Click ID. I am confused as to whether or not Twilio captures the click id.

Wondering if anyone has set up conversion tracking with Google Ads and Twilio. And if so what process you would recommend to do this. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog on using Google Analytics with Twilio. For the voice channel, you will need to embed the URL query parameters into the Twilio phone number webhook associated with the Twilio phone number in your add.

You can use Twilio API's (IncomingPhoneNumber resource to do this).

When someone calls that phone number, Twilio will pass the parameters to you application.

Think as Twilio being the web client passing the Google Analytics parameters to your web server.

[How to Capture Call Tracking Metrics in Google Analytics with Twilio Programmable Voice](https://www.twilio.com/blog/capture-call-tracking-metrics-google-analytics-twilio-programmable-voice)